# Is SKNode thread safe?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, sprite-kit, grand-central-dispatch

On an iOS game I am making with Swift, I am listening to touch events, reading the `userData`property of some `SKNode`, and updating the texture property of some other `SKSpriteNode` that are part of the scene, but to avoid any lag during the user interaction, I dispatch this update code asynchronously on the main queue, is it a good idea ?

By the way, some general question about thread safety : is there a risk only when you are writing data, or is there also a risk when reading data ?

Thank you.

Comment: if you are dispatching on the main queue, then no threading is happening, because everything else is running on the main queue as well,  the only thing that is happening is the order of which the events happen are not in line with your code

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Why isn't multithreading happening when you are dispatching asynchronously ?

Comment: because you are dispatching on the same thread,  If you have your code running on the main thread, and you dispatch to that same thread, you are still working on a single thread.  Multithreading requires 2 or more being used. Also, I can't look this up now, but I am pretty sure you want to keep everything in the main thread, and let spritekit handle all threading issues with its elements

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ok thank you I understand, just an other question : let's say you are on an other queue, such as a queue you got with `dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)`, would calling dispatch_async several times with that queue dispatch on several threads, or just on one thread to witch this queue is linked ?

Comment: that is 1 thread, the user interactive thread

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?  Do you want to update texture property on a separate thread?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Well, actually you just made me realise that I was confusing sync/async and serial/concurrent. But, out of all of the queues you'll get with QoS, how do we know which one is serial and which one is concurrent ? For instance, from what I understand, since you said that it is one thread for QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, is this queue a serial queue ?

Comment: I do not remember, but I believe you can specify what you want

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Actually, from what I understand from reading the doc, all queues you get with a QoS when calling dispatch_get_global_queue are *concurent* queues ! Therefore many threads !

Comment: From what I know, you only get 4 concurrent queues,  the ID specifies which queue you want to use, from there on in, you would have to research

Answer (score 1):

As current [documentation on `SKNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode) says in [getting started](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/getting_started_with_nodes#2985117) section:

> Ensure Node Access on the Main Thread

So, the answer for the question in the title

> Is SKNode thread safe?

is - **NO**. `SKNode` isn't thread safe, it should be modified only from the main thread.

But the answer for the second question:

> I dispatch this update code asynchronously on the main queue, is it a good idea?

will be **YES**. It's exactly what you expected to do.

As for the last question: risk is possible when reading data. If you read a constant like `let version = 3`, there will be no risk. But take a look at this example:

```
var bigLazyObject: BigObject?

func getBigLazyObject() -> BigObject {
    if let existingObject = bigLazyObject {
        return existingObject
    } else {
        let newObject = BigObject()
        bigLazyObject = newObject
        return newObject
    }
}
```

It demonstrates an unwanted creation of the second `BigObject` instance, which can occure if `getBigLazyObject()` will be called in 2 threads simultaneously. There is a chance that both threads will fall in the `else` branch of the `if` statement before `bigLazyObject` is actually created. This kind of problem should be solved when creating thread-safe singletons. In Swift they are thread-safe buy default, but in Objective-C people usually use `dispatch_once()` block.